# What is the right xpath/css to use to get each paragraph text in a single string?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

First I create a HtmlResponse And read it using scrapy:

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.selector import Selector

body = """
<div class="a">
  <p>
      text1<br> text2
  </p>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <p>
         text3
    </p>
</div>
 """
response = HtmlResponse(url='http://example.com/', body=body)
sel = Selector(response)
```

Now, I would like to extract text from this html But I get a list with 2 elements. This is what I have so far tried:

```
 sel.xpath('//div[@class="a"]/p/text()').extract()
 # [u'\n      text1', u' text2\n  ', u'\n         text3\n    ']
```

As you note I get 3 text elements for 2 paragraphs? How can I do to get only 2 text elements?

```
  [u'text1 text2',u'text3']
```

Note that I prefer not to use `BeautifulSoup` since performance is a requirement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS selectors (including Scrapy's `::text` extension):

```
>>> from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> 
>>> body = """
... <div class="a">
...   <p>
...       text1<br> text2
...   </p>
... </div>
... <div class="a">
...     <p>
...          text3
...     </p>
... </div>
...  """
>>> response = HtmlResponse(url='http://example.com/', body=body)
>>> sel = Selector(response)
>>> [u''.join(paragraph.css('::text').extract()).strip() for paragraph in sel.css('div.a > p')]
[u'text1 text2', u'text3']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 equivalent to mine but using css. I check it for the use of strip (cleaner solution).

Answer (score 0):

I come with this solution using comprhension, maybe someone else can have better alternative:

```
[''.join(x.xpath('./text()').extract()) for x in sel.xpath('//div[@class="a"]/p')]

## [u'\n      text1 aa\n  ', u'\n         text3\n    ']
```